# Ordering ggplot columns using reorder not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code like seen below, I now want to barplot `obstacles` (x) and `n` (y) while ordering bars based on `n`, so I go ahead and do the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
move_obstacles = tibble::tribble(
  ~move_approach,                           ~obstacle, ~n,
  "Relocate", "Distance from business activities", 1L,
  "Relocate",                      "No customers", 1L,
  "Relocate",                       "No services", 1L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "Cost of move", 4L,
  "Upgrade Existing", "Distance from business activities", 6L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                       "Higher rent", 1L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "Higher taxes", 2L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "No customers", 6L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                       "No services", 3L
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(obstacle,n),n)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip() +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle("Obstacles to moving")

move_obstacles
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

As you can see the bars are not in order of magnitude even though I have included code to reorder `ggplot(aes(reorder(obstacle,n),n))`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `reorder` uses the mean in case of multiple observations. Instead use `FUN=sum` if your want to order by the count:

```r
library(tidyverse)
move_obstacles = tibble::tribble(
  ~move_approach,                           ~obstacle, ~n,
  "Relocate", "Distance from business activities", 1L,
  "Relocate",                      "No customers", 1L,
  "Relocate",                       "No services", 1L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "Cost of move", 4L,
  "Upgrade Existing", "Distance from business activities", 6L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                       "Higher rent", 1L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "Higher taxes", 2L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                      "No customers", 6L,
  "Upgrade Existing",                       "No services", 3L
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(obstacle, n, FUN = sum),n)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip() +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle("Obstacles to moving")

move_obstacles
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see that this works, I am not sure I understood what you mean by "by default reorder takes the mean" the mean of what exactly?

Comment: Hi Tumaini. The mean of `n`. You have multiple obs for e.g. "No customers". As one can only reorder by one value `reorder` by default takes the mean of all `n` values (by category). In contrast `geom_col` stacks the obs, i.e. it computes the sum of n. That's why we have to tell `reorder` to use the sum too.